# How can I horizontally align bootstrap 3 radio and the radio's label?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, radio-button

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <label class="control-label in-line">Lover gender</label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" value="option1"> Male
  </label>
  <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" value="option2"> Female      </label>                       
</form>
```

Please also explain you answers.

Comment: please don't use [tag:radio] (it's about wireless transmission) but [tag:radio-button]

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use `<form class="form-inline">` for inline forms:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

There's also helper classes for inline radios:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#checkboxes-and-radios

Here's an example on Bootply that shows what you're trying to do:

http://www.bootply.com/BCSk79TPOS

The code used is:

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="radio-inline">
    <label for="option1">
      <input type="radio" id="option1"> Option 1
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="radio-inline">
    <label for="option2">
      <input type="radio" id="option2"> Option 2
    </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What if i want to lebal something for the radii

Comment: The text in my code example that reads "Option 1" and "Option 2" is the label for the radio buttons.

Comment: I've added "for" attributes to the labels and "id" attributes to the radio inputs, this will set it up so that when you click the text the radio input is focused.

Answer (score 0):

The `<label>` tag defines a label for an `<input>` element. Your first label doesn't define anything.

But, anyway, if you still want to use it, give it the same default Bootstrap class as the others below "`radio-inline`". I think checkbox-inline works as well. You just have to define the same CSS for all the labels in there.
`.radio-inline` class has some properties, different from the default browser properties for the stand-alone `label` element. That's why goes on a different line.

Hope this is the answer you were looking for.